# Ecto.Repo to check if id exists in the database, Phoenix framework

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

- How do I check if an id exists in the database?

  ```
  def get_user!(id), do: Repo.get!(User, id)
  ```
- `get_user!(id)` can be used to get the user, is there a way to check if id exists?
- I want something like below which would return true.

  `MyApp.Accounts.get_user!(user_id) == %MyApp.Accounts.User{id: user_id}`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ecto v3 supports this with [`Ecto.Repo.exists?/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:exists?/2)

```
import Ecto.Query, only: [from: 2]

Repo.exists?(from u in User, where: u.id == ^user_id)
```

Comment: Super useful! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`Repo.get!` throws an error if no record is found.
You might want to use `Repo.get` instead like

```
Repo.get(User, user_id) != nil
```

You can also define a function to check if a give user id exists

```
def user_exist_by_id(user_id)do
    #select just id to reduce payload
    query = (from u in User, where: u.id == ^user_id, select: %{id: u.id})
    found = Repo.one(query)
    #if not result, found will be nil
    found != nil
end
```